# Vue - Change state from 'watch' callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state

I'm playing around with Vue, and I've seen you can set up a 'watch' callback for when a piece of Data changes:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <input v-model="inputVal" placeholder="edit me" />
    <p>{{ inputVal }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputVal: '22'
    }
  },

  watch: {
    inputVal: function(val, oldVal) {
      console.log('inputVal changed');
      console.log(oldVal);
      console.log(val);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If I want to make a change to the data state inside the `watch.inputVal` function, how would I do that?

Comment: what *data state* do you want to change?

Comment: @JaromandaX good question, the example I gave only showed one data value, `inputVal`, and if I were to change that in that callback it would of course cause some kind of recursive problem, which is probably why you're asking! But no, I was thinking of adding a new 'data' variable that could update when inputVal changes, I'm not intending to create a never-ending loop of updates. I should have included that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```js
data() {
  return {
    inputVal: '22',
    isValueOdd: false
  }
},

watch: {
  inputVal(val, oldVal) {
    this.isValueOdd = val % 2 !== 0
  }
}
```

But generally if some of your state is dependent on some other state, it might be a better idea to use computed instead of watch:

```js
data() {
  return {
    inputVal: '22'
  }
},

computed: {
  isValueOdd() {
    return this.inputVal % 2 !== 0
  }
}
```

Computed is lazy, cached and overall easier to understand. The main purpose of watch is to execute side effects.

Comment: yes this worked, thank you. In the use case I'm thinking of, I probably do in fact want to go with 'computed', but knowing how to change the state is useful too. Thanks for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the watch you can access `data` object using `this` keyword. To make changes to `data` object you can update using `this.propertyName = newValue`.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <input v-model="inputVal" placeholder="edit me" />
    <p>{{ inputVal }}</p>
    <p>{{ anotherState }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputVal: '22',
      anotherState: 'Waiting for input',
    };
  },

  watch: {
    inputVal: function (val, oldVal) {
      console.log('inputVal changed');
      console.log(oldVal);
      console.log(val);
      this.anotherState = val + ' entered';
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In this code we have new data state named `anotherState`, it gets updated whenever `inputVal` is changed. I am not sure if I got your question correctly.   Is that something you were looking for?